# Kneser-Ney smoothing of trigrams using Python NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, smoothing

I'm trying to smooth a set of n-gram probabilities with Kneser-Ney smoothing using the Python NLTK.
Unfortunately, the whole documentation is rather sparse.

What I'm trying to do is this: I parse a text into a list of tri-gram tuples. From this list I create a FreqDist and then use that FreqDist to calculate a KN-smoothed distribution.

I'm pretty sure though, that the result is totally wrong. When I sum up the individual probabilities I get something way beyond 1. Take this code example:

```py
import nltk

ngrams = nltk.trigrams("What a piece of work is man! how noble in reason! how infinite in faculty! in \
form and moving how express and admirable! in action how like an angel! in apprehension how like a god! \
the beauty of the world, the paragon of animals!")

freq_dist = nltk.FreqDist(ngrams)
kneser_ney = nltk.KneserNeyProbDist(freq_dist)
prob_sum = 0
for i in kneser_ney.samples():
    prob_sum += kneser_ney.prob(i)
print(prob_sum)
```

The output is "41.51696428571428". Depending on the corpus size, this value grows infinitely large. That makes whatever prob() returns anything but a probability distribution.

Looking at the NLTK code I would say that the implementation is questionable. Maybe I just don't understand how the code is supposed to be used. In that case, could you give me a hint please? In any other case: do you know any working Python implementation? I don't really want to implement it myself.

Comment: that's a log probability. So `math.exp(41.51696428571428)` = 1.0729722613480671e+18, very small probability. When it grows KN-smoothing grows larger, means the probability is smaller. But it might also be that the NLTK implementation is not right, please report issue to https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. 1.0729722613480671e+18 is not very small but in fact an extremely large number. 41.51696428571428 is the sum of all probabilities returned by KneserNeyProbDist and it should be around 1.0.

Comment: Whoop, misread the +/- on the e =) Report the issue in the github.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Kneser-Ney](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/publications/download/951/Kneser-ICASSP-1995.pdf) (also have a look at [Goodman and Chen](http://www2.denizyuret.com/ref/goodman/chen-goodman-99.pdf) for a great survey on different smoothing techniques) is a quite complicated smoothing which only a few package that I am aware of got it right. Not aware of any python implementation, but you can definitely try [SRILM](http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/) if you just need probabilities, etc.

- There is a good chance that your sample has words that didn't occur in training data (aka *Out-Of-Vocabulary (OOV)* words), which if not handled properly can mess up the probabilities you get. Perhaps this can cause getting outrageously large and invalid prob?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I'm doing in the code above is simply adding the probabilities of all learned samples. So, I'm not checking probabilities of any unseen samples at all. Probabilities of unseen samples are handled strangely anyway. If i search for for an untrained (w1,w2,w3), then it checks if that one is known. If it is not, it gives a smoothed probability for (w2,w3). If that is unknown, too, it gives 0.0. So in almost all cases, you get 0.0 when checking unlearned trigrams which is absurd because I don't need smoothing for that.

Comment: @JanekBevendorff  If you are "adding" probabilities, why is it unexpected to get a final probability which is above 1?

Comment: @JanekBevendorff and am putting this as another comment: to get the probability of your corpus, you shouldn't sum probabilities if they are not log-scaled. If they are log-scaled, then summation is fine. Note \log\product = \sum\log.

Comment: When I have a corpus of n-grams then their total summed probability should be one (+/- numerical errors). Otherwise my n-gram distribution is not a probability distribution. When I take that distribution and smooth it, then I want to redistribute the probabilities a little to account for sample-errors and make some space for "unseen" events. So when I sum over my smoothed probabilities, I expect a value of 1.0 - x where 0 <= x <= 1 is the portion for unseen n-grams.

Comment: `KenLM` has more stable and updated implementation of KN smoothing and a python interface: https://github.com/kpu/kenlm

Comment: @alvas that is not KN. It's modified KN of Goodman and Chen. KenLM doesn't have any smoothing beyond modified KN implemented.

Comment: @JanekBevendorff Hmm. Each ngram has its own probability, so I don't think expecting all ngrams' probabilities to sum to one is valid. The only thing that is guaranteed to sum to one is when for a fixed context you sum over all words completing it to the right: \sum_{x\in vocab} P(x|context) = 1.

Comment: The FreqDist still sums to 1, but after smoothing it doesn't do that anymore. The SimpleGoodTuringProbDist smoothing works better, but there I end with something below 1. KenLM looks interesting, will see what I can do with that.

Answer (score 11):

I think you are misunderstanding what Kneser-Ney is computing.

From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%E2%80%93Ney_smoothing)

> The normalizing constant λ<sub>w<sub>i-1</sub></sub>
>  has value chosen carefully to make the sum of conditional probabilities p<sub>KN</sub>(w<sub>i</sub>|w<sub>i-1</sub>) equal to one.

Of course we're talking about bigrams here but the same principal is true for higher order models. Basically what this quote means is that, for a fixed context w<sub>i-1</sub> (or more context for higher order models) the probabilities of all w<sub>i</sub> must add up to one. What you are doing when you add up the probabilities of all samples is including multiple contexts, which is why you end up with a "probability" greater than 1. If you keep the context fixed, as in the following code sample, you end up with a number <= 1.

```
    from nltk.util import ngrams
    from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

    gut_ngrams = ( ngram for sent in gutenberg.sents() for ngram in ngrams(sent, 3, pad_left = True, pad_right = True, right_pad_symbol='EOS', left_pad_symbol="BOS"))
    freq_dist = nltk.FreqDist(gut_ngrams)
    kneser_ney = nltk.KneserNeyProbDist(freq_dist)

    prob_sum = 0
    for i in kneser_ney.samples():
        if i[0] == "I" and i[1] == "confess":
            prob_sum += kneser_ney.prob(i)
            print "{0}:{1}".format(i, kneser_ney.prob(i))
    print prob_sum
```

The output, based on the NLTK Gutenberg corpus subset, is as follows.

```
    (u'I', u'confess', u'.--'):0.00657894736842
    (u'I', u'confess', u'what'):0.00657894736842
    (u'I', u'confess', u'myself'):0.00657894736842
    (u'I', u'confess', u'also'):0.00657894736842
    (u'I', u'confess', u'there'):0.00657894736842
    (u'I', u'confess', u',"'):0.0328947368421
    (u'I', u'confess', u'that'):0.164473684211
    (u'I', u'confess', u'"--'):0.00657894736842
    (u'I', u'confess', u'it'):0.0328947368421
    (u'I', u'confess', u';'):0.00657894736842
    (u'I', u'confess', u','):0.269736842105
    (u'I', u'confess', u'I'):0.164473684211
    (u'I', u'confess', u'unto'):0.00657894736842
    (u'I', u'confess', u'is'):0.00657894736842
    0.723684210526
```

The reason why this sum (.72) is less than 1 is that the probability is calculated only on trigrams appearing in the corpus where the first word is "I" and the second word is "confess." The remaining .28 probability is reserved for w<sub>i</sub>s which do not follow "I" and "confess" in the corpus. This is the whole point of smoothing, to reallocate some probability mass from the ngrams appearing in the corpus to those that don't so that you don't end up with a bunch of 0 probability ngrams.

Also doesn't the line

```
    ngrams = nltk.trigrams("What a piece of work is man! how noble in reason! how infinite in faculty! in \
    form and moving how express and admirable! in action how like an angel! in apprehension how like a god! \
    the beauty of the world, the paragon of animals!")
```

compute character trigrams? I think this needs to be tokenized to compute word trigrams.

Answer (score 3):

ANSWERING TO YOUR OTHER QUESTION:

> In any other case: do you know any working Python implementation?

I just finished a Kneser-Ney implementation in Python. The code is [here](https://github.com/giovannirescia/PLN-2015/blob/practico4/languagemodeling/ngram.py); there are reports in the README also. Write me for any doubts.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11337541)

Comment: I was just answering to the question "do you know any working Python implementation?"

Comment: Except for iterating over 0-gram, but doing nothing with them, and for keeping a map of sets of previous words and next words, while the size of the set is the only thing of interest after training, this code seems descent enough. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Also, it would seem you ignore the provided discount parameter... if none is given you search for the one which minimizes perplexity, but if one is given you don't use it.. you instead use some ad-hoc method of calculating it which is different than the one you use if none is given... This seems odd.

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe Regarding to the discount parameter, you are right, the documentation is not quite correct. Actually, the parameter `D` is a flag: if it is set to `None` (default), `D` will be computed as in the paper from where I took the algorithm. If it is not `None`, the algorithm will try a few values and use the one that gives better results. That said, the discount parameter answers the question "Would you like to compute `D` or just try different values and choose the better one?". Thank you for the comment, I will modify the script to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe About the 0-gram count and "doing nothing with them", it is useful when you are working with unigrams, 0-grams (represented by `()`) count how many words there are. And about of keeping the previous and next words for a token, it helped me for debugging; but I agree that keeping only the size of the set would be better. Any other comment, please do.