# Python - Trigram Probability Distribution Smoothing Technique (Kneser Ney) in NLTK Returns Zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, probability, smoothing

I have the frequency distribution of my trigram followed by training the Kneser-Ney.
When I check for `kneser_ney.prob` of a trigram that is not in the `list_of_trigrams` I get zero! What am I doing wrong?

```py
freq_dist = nltk.FreqDist(list_of_trigrams)
kneser_ney = nltk.KneserNeyProbDist(freq_dist)
```

It even has n-1-gram in the list, this is what I want:

```py
print(kneser_ney.prob(('ئامادەكاری', 'بۆ', 'تاقیكردنەوە')))
```

This is what I have in the list

```py
('ئامادەكاری', 'بۆ', 'كارە')
```

I've scoured the web looking for anyone who has the same problem as me but I have not found any...

Comment: What is in your `list_of_trigrams`? Is there any meaning to the strings you have in your examples? What is the expected output? Perhaps you could work out a better minimal working example with clear current input, current output and expected / desired output.

Comment: I used a simple example by running the second answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242155/kneser-ney-smoothing-of-trigrams-using-python-nltk), and then adding this `print(kneser_ney.prob(('I', 'Confess', 'Nothing')))`. It returns zero as well.

Comment: I am not sure this last comment qualify for an answer to any of those. It is a bit better of a context but nowhere near as useful as producing your own [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: still, kneser ney's main idea is not returning zero in case of a new trigram. I'm out of ideas... any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are observing is perfectly normal.

From the Wikipedia page (method section) for [Kneser-Ney smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%E2%80%93Ney_smoothing#Method):

> Please note that p_KN is a proper distribution, as the values defined in above way are non-negative and sum to one.

and the probability is `0` when the `ngram` did not occurred in corpus.

Quoting from the [answer you cite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40600190/5218354):

> This is the whole point of smoothing, to reallocate some probability mass from the ngrams appearing in the corpus to those that don't so that you don't end up with a bunch of 0 probability ngrams.

The above sentence does not mean that with *Kneser-Ney smoothing* you will have a non-zero probability for any ngram you pick, it means that, given a corpus, it will assign a probability to existing ngrams in such a way that you have some *spare* probability to use for other ngrams in later analyses.
This spare probability is something *you* have to assign for non-occurring ngrams, not something that is inherent to the *Kneser-Ney smoothing*.

---

## EDIT

Just for the sake of completeness I report the code to observe the behavior (largely taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40600190/5218354), and adapted to Python 3):

```py
import nltk
nltk.download('gutenberg')
nltk.download('punkt')
```

```py
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

gut_ngrams = tuple(
    ngram for sent in gutenberg.sents()
    for ngram in ngrams(
        sent, 3, pad_left=True, pad_right=True,
        right_pad_symbol='EOS', left_pad_symbol="BOS"))
freq_dist = nltk.FreqDist(gut_ngrams)
kneser_ney = nltk.KneserNeyProbDist(freq_dist)

prob_sum = 0
for i in kneser_ney.samples():
    if i[0] == "I" and i[1] == "confess":
        prob_sum += kneser_ney.prob(i)
        print("{0}:{1}".format(i, kneser_ney.prob(i)))
print(prob_sum)
# ('I', 'confess', ','):0.26973684210526316
# ('I', 'confess', 'that'):0.16447368421052633
# ('I', 'confess', '.--'):0.006578947368421052
# ('I', 'confess', 'it'):0.03289473684210526
# ('I', 'confess', 'I'):0.16447368421052633
# ('I', 'confess', ',"'):0.03289473684210526
# ('I', 'confess', ';'):0.006578947368421052
# ('I', 'confess', 'myself'):0.006578947368421052
# ('I', 'confess', 'is'):0.006578947368421052
# ('I', 'confess', 'also'):0.006578947368421052
# ('I', 'confess', 'unto'):0.006578947368421052
# ('I', 'confess', '"--'):0.006578947368421052
# ('I', 'confess', 'what'):0.006578947368421052
# ('I', 'confess', 'there'):0.006578947368421052
# 0.7236842105263156

# trigram not appearing in corpus
print(kneser_ney.prob(('I', 'confess', 'nothing')))
# 0.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand better now, reading [this book chapter](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS-224N/asset/slp4.pdf) I thought I can get non - zero for answers always. If you can explain more on this part **This spare probability is something you have to assign for non-occurring ngrams** I'd appreciate it, if I don't get any other answers in 2 or 3 days I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: Granted that I do not know from which perspective you are looking at it. I'll try to answer. Basically, the whole idea of smoothing the probability distribution of a corpus is to transform the **True** ngram probability into an approximated proability distribution that account for unseen ngrams. To assign non-zero proability to the non-occurring ngrams, the occurring n-gram need to be modified. Kneser-Ney smoothing is one such modification. The probability that is left *unallocated* is somewhat outside of *Kneser-Ney smoothing*, and there are several approaches for that. See p.19 below eq.4.37

Comment: One way of assigning a non-zero probability to an unknown word: "If we want to include an unknown word<UNK>, it’s just included as a regular vocabulary entry with count zero, and hence its probability will be λ(ε)/|V|" (quoting your source)

Comment: Thank again for explaining it so nicely! you confirmed an idea that will help me get unstuck in this project (putting the unknown trigram in freq dist with a zero count and train the kneser ney again). I should add your name to my acknowledgment in my master's thesis!